# Dual Boot: Ubuntu installation not detecting existing windows operating system

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-7, boot-repair

In my attempt to set up a dual boot system, by installing Ubuntu 14.04 onto my system with Windows 7, I have encountered a pretty stubborn problem.

I have loaded ubuntu into a bootable USB device.

When installing Ubuntu, whether through "try ubuntu w/o installing" or the other "install Ubuntu" option, Ubuntu never presents the "install alongside windows option".

The only two options that I have are the 1. erase all data and install ubuntu on drive and 2. do other stuff (display partitions)

---

Looking at posts by folks who have encountered this issue in the past, I have attempted some of the various suggested solutions.. without avail.

fixparts
remove dmraid

I have a boot repair log up:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7522909/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Windows is installed in BIOS boot from MBR(msdos) drive. It does look like you have an UEFI system as you booted Boot-Repair in UEFI mode. Best to always boot in BIOS mode. Was system originally Windows 8? Install of Windows 7 does not correctly convert from gpt to MBR. Or is Windows hibernated? http://www.rodsbooks.com/missing-parts/index.html

Comment: I was not aware of it. The system was originally windows 7 (windows 8 compatible). I do not believe windows is hibernated.

Comment: Use Windows to shrink Windows NTFS partition to make room for more partitions for Ubuntu. Reboot and let it run chkdsk to update to its new size. Then does gparted shows Windows? If so create a partition for / (root) and swap. And then use Something else mount / and format it, it should auto find swap and let you install.

Comment: Yup! That seemed to be the issue. After following the specific instructions for UEFI systems found here: http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/11/05/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-hardware/ .... my dual boot is fully up and running! Thanks oldfred!

Answer (score 0):

I would make a partition for ubuntu with gparted, then install ubuntu on this partition and lastly I would get [GRUB](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Installation).
This would be the do-it-yourself-way but for those where the preconfigured options fail it seems to be the only choice.

GRUB is the standard bootloader under most linux distributions. To keep it simple, the bootloader is the first software program that runs when a computer starts. It detects and gives all the installed operting systems and gives you the opportunity to choose between them.